# How do i share data between different lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

So i need some help with lambda here.

I built 5 lambdas process my products with a few external apis, like check prices, get better images and so on.

Each lambda right now has a json file with all my Rds connection string's. And im on my way of moving other processes i do with crons/jobs with lambda as well but i am worried that i will end up copying and pasting that data and if i add one more rds i will need to edit all my lambdas.

What is the best way to share that information?

I thought about S3 but i feel is not that safe to have all my databases access there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure which RDS engine you are using but if you are using MySQL or Aurora then you can use IAM roles to authenticate to your RDS DB instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon recommends using SSM Parameter Store to store variables (replacing environment variables) for Lambda (and other services). SSM Parameter Store supports encryption / descryption. Perfect for storing your DB credentials in one location that can be shared (within the same region).

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

[SSM Parameter Store](https://hackernoon.com/you-should-use-ssm-parameter-store-over-lambda-env-variables-5197fc6ea45b)

[The right way to store secrets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/the-right-way-to-store-secrets-using-parameter-store/)

Answer (score 0):

We use DynamoDB to share data. One more good thing about DynamoDB is Lambda can subscribe to DynamoDB stream and update the data as it changes.

If you have 5 different lambda's then you can subscribe to the DynamoDB stream and update whenever data in DynamoDB changes.

**More on DynamoDB Streams and Lambda Trigggers:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Hope it helps.